# Poor sound quality

Tags: sound, quality

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu. Everything is fine, but I think that the audio quality is significantly worse than on Windows. I modified daemon.conf and it’s slightly better than before but still Windows is a bit better. Is there anything else I can do to improve an audio quality?

I have Huawei Matebook D14 with Ryzen 5 if that’s important.

Answer (score 1):

You can install pulseaudio-equalizer to improve the sound quality